# How can I conver string to double value in c?

Tags: c, string, double

I want to get the equivalent double number of any word.

I use atof, but it give me zero output.

How can I solve it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
printf("%f\n", *(double*)"hello");
}
```

Comment: Umm.... what?  Please explain what you are trying to do, 'cos it doesn't make much sense.  "hello" is not a float in any meaningful way.

Comment: `atof()` expect a string _which represents a number_. The string `"hello"` does not represent a number.

Comment: What is the result you expect?

Comment: I know hello, it isn't float. I want to convert it to float number like this code      #include <stdio.h>

char string[] = "skcoR++C";

int main(){
    printf("%f\n", *(double*)string);
    getchar();
} this code doesnt work for any word except "skcoR++C",so i try to use atof

Comment: What is the output you expect from the code in your comment?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you did not read the documentation of `atof()`, or `strtod()`
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtod.htm
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/

Answer (score 0):

Doubles are floating point numbers, essentially non-integer numbers.
"hello" is not a valid string representation of a double. Try a number instead, for example

```
printf("%f\n", atof("3.141"));
```